# How to make cotton for Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

How could you make cotton, as below, using EEVEE?

[image]

Comment: did you try volume?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.